# Using Java and Mysql getting exception com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 getting this exception

```
        private String selectCustDetail= "SELECT NAME, PASSWORD, RESID, ACTIVATED, USERTYPE FROM USERDETAIL WHERE MOBILENO=?";

    ResultSet rs;
        //PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null ;
        try {
        //  preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectCustDetail);
 preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectCustDetail);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, mobileno.toString().trim());

         rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectCustDetail );
        while (rs.next()) {
        //  LOGGER.info("fetching - 1" + mobileno);
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            userDetai.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            userDetai.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            userDetai.setRestaurant(rs.getString("resId"));
            userDetai.setActivated(rs.getString("activated"));
            userDetai.setType(rs.getString("userType"));
        //  LOGGER.info("fetching - 2" + userDetai.getActivated());


        }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //LOGGER.info("Exception - " + e.getMessage());
            dinepostcons.msg = dinepostcons.dbError;
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {try {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectCustDetail );
```

to

```
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

You want the method that invokes your `preparedStatement` with bind parameters. Not the method from `Statement` that takes a `String` without bind parameters.

Comment: Ah, the abuse of inheritance that is the JDBC API...

Comment: Thank you... I was overlooking this from past 1 hour. Thanks again

Comment: @BoristheSpider They did address it in more recent JDBC version by requiring drivers to throw an exception when the executeXXX methods taking a string are called on a prepared or callable statement, but in MySQL that still only happens 'by accident', and not by intentional adherence to the spec.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  wonderful; a runtime error as a replacement for compile time type safety. I do wonder if they'll eventually overhaul the whole shebang like they did with the date time API...

Comment: @BoristheSpider The price you pay for backwards compatibility. I'd wager that if JDBC would be designed today a different choice would be made.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel too right! Backwards compatibility is getting rather _expensive_ these days. And the approach of the Java team to OO has radically changed - just remember `Properties` and `Stack`; I very much doubt the same mistakes would be made again. Joshua Bloch's mantra of "prefer composition over inheritance" speaks of lessons hard learnt...